# Java - parameters 'cannot be resolved to a variable' error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm having this problem with my code, and I know it has to deal with scope, but I've been looking over it for a long time and I can't seem to find the fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It seems as though all the errors deal with the parameters I have set in my first class "Stock."

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 

    close cannot be resolved to a variable,
    price cannot be resolved to a variable,
    change cannot be resolved to a variable,
    close cannot be resolved to a variable,
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Stock
{
   String Symbol;
   String Name;
   double previousClosingPrice;
   double currentPrice;

   Stock(String s, String n, double previousClosingPrice, double currentPrice)
   {
      Symbol = s;
      Name = n;
   }
   public String getName() { 
      return Name; }

   public String getSymbol() { 
      return Symbol; }

   public double setClosingPrice(double close)
   {
      previousClosingPrice = close;
      return close;
   }

   public double currentPrice(double price)
   {
      currentPrice = price;
      return price;
   }

   public double getChangePercent(double change)
   {
      change = (currentPrice - previousClosingPrice) / currentPrice * 100;
      return change;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      System.out.println(Name + " stock closing price is $" + setCurrentPrice(price));
   }
}


public class Test_Stock
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Stock s1 = new Stock("GOG", "Google", 134.67, 131.98);
      Stock s2 = new Stock("MSF", "Microsoft", 156.52, 161.22);


      System.out.println("Google stock: ");
      System.out.println("    Symbol: " + s1.getSymbol());
      System.out.println("    Closing price: " + s1.setClosingPrice(close));
      System.out.println("    Current price: " + s1.setCurrentPrice(price));
      System.out.println("    Change percent: " + s1.getChangePercent(change));
      s1.toString();

      System.out.println("Google stock: ");
      System.out.println("    Symbol: " + s2.getSymbol());
      System.out.println("    Closing price: " + s2.setClosingPrice(close));
      System.out.println("    Current price: " + s2.setCurrentPrice(price));
      System.out.println("    Change percent: " + s2.getChangePercent(change));
      s2.toString();
   }

}
```

Comment: `COG` -> `"COG"` etc (i.e. you have forgotten the quotes around the strings)

Comment: Those variables are undefined in your `main()' method. This is  rather trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Stock object takes a String as first and second input:

```
Stock(String s, String n, double previousClosingPrice, double currentPrice)
```

As it stands right now, you are not giving it Strings (I assume typo, you forgot the double-quotes), so change your lines to:

```
  Stock s1 = new Stock("GOG", "Google", 134.67, 131.98);
  Stock s2 = new Stock("MSF", "Microsoft", 156.52, 161.22);
```

Thats for first part of the error message.

The next problem you have, is that you have a typo in your currentPrice() method - I assume it needs to be `setCurrentPrice`.

Next: your toString() is missing a return statement.

Next: your variables that you are using like `close`, `price`, `change` are not set anywhere. You need to set them somewhere before using them as parameter input.

Comment: @clanktree are you using an IDE? It would help you greatly to find all those errors yourself :)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code, but I only got the compilation errors. I just downloaded it today, so I'm not sure if I have it setup to debug properly.

Comment: @clanktree Im afraid you dont if it hasn't complained about all those errors. You better sort it out before you continue with anything you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two lines from `main`, for example:

```
  System.out.println("    Closing price: " + s2.setClosingPrice(close));
  System.out.println("    Current price: " + s2.setCurrentPrice(price));
```

You are referring to two variables, `close` and `price`.

Neither of these are declared in `main`.

Neither of them are declared as member variables of class `Stock`.

In short, they do not exist in any applicable scope.  You may have used similar-looking names for a couple of methods, but they are not names that are available where you are now using them.

---

I think you're confused about how parameter-passing works.  If for example I declare a method:

```
void myMethod(int fubar) { ... }
```

and then call it thus:

```
myMethod(42);
```

then within this particular invocation of `myMethod`, the variable `fubar` will have value 42.  Similarly if I call it like this:

```
int xyz = 1 + 2 + 3;
myMethod(xyz);
```

in this invocation of `myMethod`, `fubar` is 6. All I'm trying to say here is that `fubar` is a variable that will receive a value from the call; the name is not automatically available anywhere outside the method that defines it, and neither are you required to use the same name.